# Prove that $ \sqrt{2} = \frac{7}{5} (1-\frac{1}{50})^{-1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been trying to expand the RHS using Taylor Series expansion. Am I on the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Square both sides.

Comment: **HINT**: $(1-\frac{1}{50})^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{50}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{49}{50}}}=\sqrt{\frac{50}{49}}$

Comment: I guess I was waaaay overthinking this one. Thanks.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal would you please be respectful of people who are learning these things? We all were there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{7}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{7}{5\sqrt{\frac{49}{50}}}=\frac{7}{5\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}}}=\frac{\sqrt{50}}{5}=\frac{\sqrt{25}\sqrt{2}}{5}=\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the title question: $$\frac75(\frac{49}{50})^{-\frac12}=\frac75.\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{7}=\sqrt2$$

Comment: You need $-1/2$.

Comment: There's a typo: It should be $-1/2$, not $1/2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\frac{7}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{50} \right)^{-1/2} =\frac{7}{5}\sqrt{\frac{50}{49}}
$$

can you do from this?

Answer (score 0):

Notice,  $$RHS=\frac{7}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{-1/2}$$
$$=\frac{7}{5}\left(\frac{50-1}{50}\right)^{-1/2}$$
$$=\frac{7}{5}\left(\frac{49}{50}\right)^{-1/2}$$
$$=\frac{7}{5}\left(\frac{50}{49}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$=\frac{7}{5}\left(\frac{2\cdot 5^2 }{7^2}\right)^{1/2}$$
$$=\frac{7}{5}\left(\frac{5\cdot 2^{1/2} }{7}\right)$$
$$=2^{1/2}=\sqrt 2=LHS$$

Answer (score 0):

For the expression $\frac{7}{5}(1-\frac{1}{50})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, we'll first evaluate $1-\frac{1}{50}$.

We'll then take the $\frac{49}{50}$ that we're left with and evaluate it to the $-1$ power. Our expression now looks like this:

$\frac{7}{5}(\frac{50}{49})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

We then take the square root of $\frac{50}{49}$, giving us $\frac{5\sqrt2}{7}$. Our expression now looks like this:

$\frac{7}{5}*\frac{5\sqrt2}{7}$

We cancel out the $7$s and $5$s, leaving us with $\sqrt2$.

$QED$.